# Delete every row with a particular string in it

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using Microsoft Word 2010.

I have a document spanning thousands of pages.  I need to write a macro that deletes every paragraph that begins with the string `mystring`.  How would I write this?

EDIT: I have figured out how to write a macro and how to delete a paragraph once my cursor is at the beginning of the paragraph.  I need to find a way to do a "find" search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim d As Document
Dim p As Paragraph

Set d = ActiveDocument

For Each p In d.Paragraphs
    If Left(p.Range, Len("Asdfsadfsdsd")) = "Asdfsadfsdsd" Then
        p.Range.Delete
    End If
Next p
```